# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

Im trying to import my `SignupLoginForm.jsx` file using

```
import SignupLoginForm from '../container/SignupLoginForm';
```

to my `Homepage.jsx` file.

`SignupLoginForm.jsx` is located in `client/container/SignupLoginForm.jsx`. `Homepage.jsx` is located in `client/components/homepage/HomePage.jsx`.

I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./client/components/homepage/HomePage.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../container/SignupLoginForm in /Users/Proj_V/client/components/homepage
 @ ./client/components/homepage/HomePage.jsx 23:23-62
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
import SignupLoginForm from '../../container/SignupLoginForm';
```

Since your `container` folder is two level up from the `Homepage.jsx` file you need to use `../` twice.

Meaning of `./`, `../` -

`./` means the current directory, which means stay in the current folder and search for the file in this.

`../` means the parent of the current directory/file, means go to one level up and search for the file.

For Example Lets say you have two files `file1.js` and `file2.js` at these paths, you want to import file2 from file1, **Imagine your folder structure as Tree data structure** :

**Case 1.**

`file1` -> `a/b/c/file1.js`

`file2` -> `a/b/c/file2.js`

since files present in the same folder u can directly import it like this : `./file2.js`.

**Case 2.**

`file1` -> `a/b/c/file1.js`

`file2` -> `a/b/c/d/file2.js`

in this case file2 present inside `d` which is at the same level of `file1`, you can import it like this: `./d/file2.js`.

**Case 3.**

`file1` -> `a/b/c/file1.js`

`file2` -> `a/b/file2.js`

in this case `file2` present at the parent level of `file1`, so you need to go one step up by using `../`, like this: `../file2.js`

**Case 4.**

`file1` -> `a/b/c/file1.js`

`file2` -> `a/file2.js`

in this case `file2` present at the level of parent of parent of `file1`, so you need to go 2 step up by using `../` twice like this: `../../file2.js`.

Simple rule: `./` means search in the same folder, `../` go one step up directry and search. We can use the combination also like: `.././`

Comment: Thank you so much Mayank. Do you know any resources regarding directories? Your solution was right but Ii dont understand when you say that my container folder is two level up

Comment: updated my answer with basic examples, please check, let me know if u need any help in this :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mayank's answer above I  would suggest you to use 'babel-root-import' plugin which will help you to import and require with root based path.

Eg: From your HomePage you can access SignupLoginForm as below:

```
import SignupLoginForm from '~/container/SignupLoginForm';
```

For more details refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-root-import